# How can I deal with NaN's when trying to make a histogram of forecast errors

Tags: r

I'm very new to R, and have been trying to learn time series analysis from https://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/timeseries.html#time-series-analysis. In the middle it outlines how to create a histogram of forecast errors with the code:

```
plotForecastErrors <- function(forecasterrors)
{
# make a histogram of the forecast errors:
mybinsize <- IQR(forecasterrors)/4
mysd   <- sd(forecasterrors)
mymin  <- min(forecasterrors) - mysd*5
mymax  <- max(forecasterrors) + mysd*3
# generate normally distributed data with mean 0 and standard deviation mysd
mynorm <- rnorm(10000, mean=0, sd=mysd)
mymin2 <- min(mynorm)
mymax2 <- max(mynorm)
if (mymin2 < mymin) { mymin <- mymin2 }
if (mymax2 > mymax) { mymax <- mymax2 }
# make a red histogram of the forecast errors, with the normally distributed data overlaid:
mybins <- seq(mymin, mymax, mybinsize)
hist(forecasterrors, col="red", freq=FALSE, breaks=mybins)
# freq=FALSE ensures the area under the histogram = 1
# generate normally distributed data with mean 0 and standard deviation mysd
myhist <- hist(mynorm, plot=FALSE, breaks=mybins)
# plot the normal curve as a blue line on top of the histogram of forecast errors:
points(myhist$mids, myhist$density, type="l", col="blue", lwd=2)
}
```

My residual starts with two NA values and I get the error:

Error in quantile.default(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm,  : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

So how do I make it either skip the first two NA values? Also should my residuals have NA values at all?

Comment: Your residuals may be `NA` with invalid input. (Be thankful they're `NA` ... often they're not, and there's no obvious indicator that the inputs were not within the expected ranges.) To remove `NA` values, you can use `na.omit`, though I suspect something else may be wrong with your residuals-expectations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to clean NAs from forecasterrors:

```
forecasterrors <- forecasterrors[!is.na(forecasterrors)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer using only `!is.na()` was part of the answer that allowed this function to work in my setup.  Additionally, I needed to include the `replace()` function. As an example, here is how I structured the statement:

```
plotForecastErrors(replace(rainseriesforecasts2$residuals, is.na(rainseriesforecasts2$residuals), 0))
```